# Read file from parent project in gradle multi project

Tags: java, gradle

My Project Structure is something like:

```
Parent:
   sub 1
     src
      ....
   sub 2
     src
   myFile.json
```

I need to access this file myFile.json in `sub 2` which resides in the main(parent) project directory. 
I tried `getResources` and `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.json"));`
However, I am unable to access the file.

If however, the file resides in the sub2, the file can be accessed.

Please help how too access it

Comment: some how it worked with BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../myFile.json"));

Answer (score -1):

You should give the whole path to the file you want to access.

```
File f = new File("sub 2/src/myFile.json");
```